# Where is genesis block stored and how can I retrieve it from an existing network (Hyperledger Fabric)?

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric

I would like to retrieve the genesis block from an existing Hyperledger Fabric network.
I found this method

```
docker cp peer0.org1.example.com:channelall.block .
```

Now, where exactly is genesis block stored, what is the path to it?
Also, what if the network is stopped, so docker containers are not running, how do I find it then?

I'm using docker-compose. I have a multi node structure, with 3 nodes - one orderer and two organizations (one node per each). Each peer is split into 4 containers: cli, peer0, peer1 and ca.

Comment: We need more informations on your network ? Is it a docker compose ? Have you an app or did you used cli peer to setup your network (or maybe you used a script to setup everything). Share your compose file if you have one , or share more info on your network :)

Answer (score 0):

As in every Blockchain, the genesis block is stored by every node as the first block of the chain. In Hyperledger Fabric, the genesis block is stored by orderer and peers.

On the other hand, as you are using docker, the data of each container is stored at the docker container or at the volumen linked to it. So, the chain of the Blockhcain is there. However, you can retrieve it accesing to the path, you have to convert it. For that, you would execute the following commands:

- First of all, you would get the block: `peer channel fetch 0 nameForIt_genesisBlock.block -c $CHANNEL_NAME --orderer orderer.example.com:7050`
- The, you will transform it to a json file with the `configtxlator` tool, executing the following command: `configtxlator proto_decode --input nameForIt_genesisBlock.block --type common.Block > nameForIt_genesisBlock.json`

Comment: how can we fetch details from genesis block if I haven't created any channel yet? is there any way?

Answer (score 0):

Genesis block got created by taking the input from configtx.yaml, and following way it got created and stored somewhere on your local :

./bin/configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsOrdererGenesis -channelID system-channel -outputBlock **./system-genesis-block/genesis.block**

Reference : https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/main/test-network/network.sh

> The configtxgen tool is used to create the genesis block. Configtxgen
> consumes a "configtx.yaml" file that contains the definitions for the
> sample network. The genesis block is defined using the
> "TwoOrgsApplicationGenesis" profile at the bottom of the file.

After that usually mounted to the orderer docker container via this :

**volumes:
- ../system-genesis-block/genesis.block:/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block**

Each orderer running in HLF network will have that genesis block mounted else the orderer will not run.

So where the genesis block as a file located ?, Its located on the mounted directory.

Reference : https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/main/test-network/docker/docker-compose-test-net.yaml

[image: Genesis block Shot 2022-01-13 at 8.22.22 am]